# Treating outliers when missing values are in large amount

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, missing-data

I am having a hard time coming up with a strategy to treat missing values and outliers in a dataset where more than 75% of values are missing. The present values are somehow extremely variable.

If I decide to set all the missing values to the mean, the number of outliers grows by a factor 40, so this means that the choice of the missing values treatment strategy influences the outliers treatment strategy.

At first glance, I would think in a physical way and assume that the missing values may be distributed similarly to the present values, thus outliers should be individuated **before** treating the missing values.

But this poses me a problem: when I set all the missing values to the mean I will automatically generate outliers, that will of course affect the accuracy of my predictors (a neural network, random forest, or linear regression). This would not solve my problem.

How should I treat these NA values to learn the most I can from my dataset?

Comment: I'd certainly drop all variables whose missing data is bigger than 15%.

Comment: With so much missing I guess context is important. What is the missing mechanism?  Some outside sources of information? Look into multiple imputation, maybe bayesian methods (with informative priors.)  To say more we need much more details.